# Multipeer connectivity for android

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, compatibility, multipeer-connectivity

So I'm trying to build an app that uses iOS 7  Multipeer Connectivity framework on the iPhone, but I'm now trying to connect the iPhone to an Android device using the same technology. Is this possible?

Is there something like Apple's multipeer connectivity framework for Android, or is there any way of connecting an iPhone to an Android device without using internet or mobile services, but using Wifi and bluetooth only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer data between iOS and Android via Bluetooth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884705/transfer-data-between-ios-and-android-via-bluetooth)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 Multipeer Connectivity and Android WiFi Direct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067794/ios-7-multipeer-connectivity-and-android-wifi-direct)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a bit delayed, but technologies have evolved since so there is certainly new info around.

As iOS has yet to open up an API for WiFi Direct and Multipeer Connectivity is iOS only, I believe the best way to approach this is to use BLE, which is supported by both platforms (some better than others).

On iOS a device can act both as a BLE Central and BLE Peripheral at the same time, on Android the situation is more complex as not all devices support the BLE Peripheral state. Also the Android BLE stack is very unstable (to date).

If your use case is feature driven, I would suggest to look at Frameworks and Libraries that can do cross platform p2p for you, without you needing to build it up from scratch.

For example: p2pkit.io or google nearby

Disclaimer: I work for Uepaa, developing p2pkit.io for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to connect with android over bluetooth, **but you can connect with wifi** using the Multipeer framework I believe. I know the developer of [spaceteam](http://www.sleepingbeastgames.com/spaceteam/) accomplished this with his game. I'm not sure how exactly but it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Mutipeer connectivity cannot connect iOS and Android devices. Firechat & Spaceteam are using their own implementation.

More information here:

A couple of weeks after its iOS launch, FireChat made its debut on Android. Since Android doesn’t support Apple’s Multipeer Connectivity Framework, developer Open Garden had to build its own mesh networking technology to enable off-the-grid messaging across Android devices. However, FireChat messaging hasn’t been possible between iOS and Android. That is, until now. Open Garden has just updated FireChat to allow for off-the-grid messaging even between iOS and Android devices. While it declines to reveal the exact details of how it managed to make Apple’s multi-peer framework and its Android mesh network connect with each other, Open Garden has told TechCrunch that its cross-platform capability uses peer-to-peer Wi-Fi and Bluetooth personal area networking.

Source: http://appadvice.com/appnn/2014/06/firechat-now-supports-off-the-grid-messaging-between-ios-and-android

Answer (score 2):

Google Nearby can do it. To cross platform, Google Nearby Message Api can do it.