# Android to iOS connect via WiFi or using Multipeer connectivity or using WiFi direct

Tags: android, ios, wifi-direct, multipeer-connectivity

So I am developing an APP and I need to connect multiple android and multiple Iphone to send text data without any internet connection or service provider data network. 
So one of the phone will have to act as a server to relay information between them. But the app will have to decide which phone will be the server and if a phone that is the server leaves the conversation then another phone will pickup as the server this will all be done with some smart programming but before I get there.

I know Android WiFi direct can do a one to many connection setup which makes it easy to connect android phone and accomplish the task between android phone only. But the problems comes when I need to connect Iphone with the android phones. Since the Iphone must be able to act as a server as well.

I would like to know a few things:

1. Can I connect Android and Iphone via WiFi Direct?
2. Can I connect Android and Iphone using Multipeer connectivity feature on Iphone?
3. Is there anyway to create a soft access point using Iphone? I know android can do this via WiFi direct feature.

If non of these can work can you suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067794/ios-7-multipeer-connectivity-and-android-wifi-direct&ei=3l9hU6OZIaXM2gWmwoHYCA&usg=AFQjCNGIgmiyzuMCVQDHp7m-wGWZXCgYWQ&bvm=bv.65636070,d.cWc) it doesn't look possible

I wonder though if both OS allow enough control over the WiFi transceiver if you couldn't just write an app that could what you are asking and just bypassing the built in software architecture all together. I would think Bluetooth would be too weak except in extremely dense device saturation environments, but just for proof of concept that could be another route to take. My guess though is that you just wouldn't get that level of control over any of the radios inside a phone through the current OS.