# Communicate ios device with android device using bluetooth/wi-fi direct/BLE api or any other way

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, wifi

Is it possible to carry out Communication of an ios device with android device using bluetooth/wi-fi direct/BLE api or any other way without server (internet) and its ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Bluetooth / LE: Not possible without Jailbreak
- Wifi-Direct: Not
  supported by iOS

Unfortunately, there is no way to communciate in both ways without a wifi network both are connected to. While this means it also works without an Internet connection, it still requires a wifi network.

Comment: Where did the claim "Wifi-Direct: Not supported by iOS" come from? AFAIK, Apple's framework MultipeerConnectivity supports 3 transfer methods: Bluetooth, Wi-Fi **and Wi-Fi Direct**. That means that iOS must support Wi-Fi Direct on some level.

Comment: It's not the same kind of Wifi Direct as supported by Android, eg you cannot connect Android and iOS via Wifi Direct AFAICT. See this question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067794/ios-7-multipeer-connectivity-and-android-wifi-direct