# I would want to connect to any non-iOS Wifi-Direct enabled devices from my iPhone or iPad. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, wifi-direct

I learnt about MultiPeer Connectivity Framework. But I could see that it only connects iOS devices, whereas I need to connect an iPhone with non-iOS device through Wifi-Direct.

Comment: Did you check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906948/peer-to-peer-android-and-ios-with-wifi-direct-multipeer-connectivity

Comment: Yes I did. But I need to know whether someone has tried and made it working or not.