# Is it possible to connect iOS MultipeerConnectivity with android?

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, multipeer-connectivity

Is it possible to connect iOS MultipeerConnectivity framework with an android device?

I would like to connect both platforms with this kind of connectivity.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Peer to peer android and iOS with Wifi direct (multipeer connectivity?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906948/peer-to-peer-android-and-ios-with-wifi-direct-multipeer-connectivity)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not possible, based on the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906948/peer-to-peer-android-and-ios-with-wifi-direct-multipeer-connectivity).

There does seem to be some open source alternatives, though I can't vouch for any of them personally.

Edit: Just found the flag as duplicate functionality, you can probably ignore this.